# Neo4j cypher create node issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Below is Cypher query

```
WITH [{commitID:'InvestmentProject',toolName:'GIT',projectId:'InvestmentProject1',vector:'DEVELOPMENT',committer:'XYZ developer',updaterValue:'Some random filed may be commitid',creationDate:1515496950544},{commitID:'InvestmentProject',toolName:'JIRA',projectId:'InvestmentProject2',vector:'DEVELOPMENT',committer:'XYZ developer',updaterValue:'Some random filed may be commitid',creationDate:1515496950544},{commitID:'RetailProject',toolName:'GIT',projectId:'RetailProject1',vector:'DEVELOPMENT',committer:'XYZ developer',updaterValue:'Some random filed may be commitid',creationDate:1515496950544}] AS props  
UNWIND props AS event
MATCH (m:METADATA:DATATAGGING)
WHERE m.inputValue = event.projectId WITH m,props 
UNWIND props AS properties
CREATE (n:TESTDATATAGGING)
SET n=properties,n.level_1=m.level_1,n.level_2=m.level_2,n.level_3=m.level_3,n.level_4=m.level_4 return n
```

This is creating 9 nodes instead of 3

```
UNWIND props AS event
MATCH (m:METADATA:DATATAGGING)
WHERE m.inputValue = event.projectId
WITH m -----> returns 3 nodes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: How many `m` nodes does the first `MATCH/WHERE` find?

Comment: It returns 3 nodes as expected.

Comment: I just tried your query after creating 3 `:METADATA:DATATAGGING` nodes with the expected `inputValue` properties, and your query is producing 9 `:TESTDATATAGGING` nodes for me.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. Ideally I want these 3 nodes properties to be set in new nodes I am creating along with CREATE (n:TESTDATATAGGING)
SET n=properties. Is there is way to modify Map with values returns by UNWIND props AS event
MATCH (m:METADATA:DATATAGGING)
WHERE m.inputValue = event.projectId
WITH m

Comment: OK, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create 3 `TESTDATATAGGING` nodes, your query should not be `UNWIND`ing `props` a second time (which is what would cause the 9 creations, since every `m` row from the first `MATCH` would be turned into 3 rows after the second `UNWIND`).

Instead, you should just reuse `event`, like this:

```
WITH [{commitID:'InvestmentProject',toolName:'GIT',projectId:'InvestmentProject1',vector:'DEVELOPMENT',committer:'XYZ developer',updaterValue:'Some random filed may be commitid',creationDate:1515496950544},{commitID:'InvestmentProject',toolName:'JIRA',projectId:'InvestmentProject2',vector:'DEVELOPMENT',committer:'XYZ developer',updaterValue:'Some random filed may be commitid',creationDate:1515496950544},{commitID:'RetailProject',toolName:'GIT',projectId:'RetailProject1',vector:'DEVELOPMENT',committer:'XYZ developer',updaterValue:'Some random filed may be commitid',creationDate:1515496950544}] AS props  
UNWIND props AS event
MATCH (m:METADATA:DATATAGGING)
WHERE m.inputValue = event.projectId
CREATE (n:TESTDATATAGGING)
SET n=event,n.level_1=m.level_1,n.level_2=m.level_2,n.level_3=m.level_3,n.level_4=m.level_4
RETURN n;
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. I could reuse the event object. I thought I need to unwind again with new data from MATCH. Thank you, this resolves my query. I am accepting it.